# Counting number of occurrences BEFORE row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I'm fairly new to SQL, so I am not sure if this is possible. I have a hierarchal database and I am trying to build a query that will order results by this hierarchy.

I cannot order by column 'TreeLevel' (see example below) because this way the children will be separated from their parents. Furthermore the needed order is dependent on thee different columns in various tables, so a cte becomes way more complex for my current knowledge.

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| TreeLevel |  Code   | Parent Code |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
|         1 |  0770.1 |             |
|         2 | 0770.50 |      0770.1 |
|         3 |  0804.5 |     0770.50 |
|         2 | 0770.12 |      0770.1 |
|         1 |  0891.1 |             |
|         2 |    0980 |      0891.1 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

**I want to order by determining the number of occurrences of the TreeLevel AT each row. So, for the second '2' in TreeLevel, this number should be 2. For the third 2 however, this number should be three. Is this in any way possible?**

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here is the SQL I have now:

```
Select ChildComp.TreeLevel, 
ChildComp.Code, 
ISNULL(ChildComp.Specification, '') AS Specification,
dbo.stkCommodities.Code as 'Stock Item Commodity Code', 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(dbo.stkCategories.Code,'') = 'SA-NP' THEN 'SA-NP' ELSE '' END AS 'Category Code', 
ChildComp.Quantity,
LEFT(ChildComp.Description, CHARINDEX(' -', ChildComp.Description, 1))  as posnr, 
stkStockItems.Description as 'Stock Item Description',
ParentComp.Code AS 'Parent Component Code',
CASE WHEN ISNULL(ChildComp.Specification, '') = '' Then ParentComp.Code Else CONCAT(ParentComp.Code, '_', ISNULL(ChildComp.Specification, '')) END AS 'Component Code + Rev'
From dbo.astComponents AS ChildComp
LEFT Join dbo.astAssets ON ChildComp.AssetId = astAssets.Id 
LEFT Join dbo.stkStockItems ON ChildComp.Code = stkStockItems.Code
LEFT Join dbo.stkCommodities ON stkStockItems.CommodityId = stkCommodities.Id
LEFT Join dbo.stkCategories ON stkStockItems.CategoryId = stkCategories.Id
LEFT Join dbo.astComponents AS ParentComp ON ChildComp.ParentComponentId = ParentComp.Id
LEFT Join dbo.stkStockItems As ParentItems ON ParentComp.Code = ParentItems.Code
LEFT Join dbo.stkCommodities AS ParentCom ON ParentItems.CommodityId = ParentCom.Id
Where astAssets.Code = '2018010084' AND (dbo.stkCommodities.Code <> 'RM' OR dbo.stkCommodities.Code IS NULL ) AND
(ParentCom.Code <> 'WA' OR ParentCom.Code IS NULL )
```

With the tables:

[dbo.astComponents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbg50.png)

[dbo.astAssets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1RVK.png)

[dbo.stkStockItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrV7a.png)

[dbo.stkCommodities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIVN0.png)

[dbo.stkCategories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO3ym.png)

Apologies for sharing the tables as links, but these are really quite long tables

Comment: So, for your sample data, what is the order you're after?

Comment: The order I'd like is as shown in the example.

Comment: How do you get your current result, using a Recursive Select?

Comment: I currently don't have any results ordered the way I want, otherwise I would not be asking! :)
I am thinking of doing an ORDER BY CASE

Comment: what you have shown is the expected result. So can you show us how the sample data looks like ?

Comment: Added the SQL and tables as requested

Comment: can you share actual data, rather than screenshots, a top 1000 for each table will suffice to research for solution

Comment: @HarsimranjeetSingh would an excel file work?

Comment: With this google search:  `sql server recursive cte ordering hierarchical result` you will find lots of other similar questions, all of which have answers that can be adapted to fit your need.   I picked the one I thought was closest.   Basically, you need to generate a node path in the recursive CTE and order by that in the outer query.

Comment: Tab, my question is marked in bold and thus I don't see why you marked my thread as a duplicate

Comment: Sure excel will

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as lev, code, parent
      from t
      where parent is null
      union all
      select lev + 1, t.code, t.parent
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parent = cte.code
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: Gordon, like I mentioned I have looked into cte's but I cannot seem to make them work since the order is dependent on thee different columns in various tables. Not only do I need to order on TreeLevel, I also need to order on position nr. while additionally looking at (parent) codes.